# Error while opening an app hosted on a SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, survey-list, mobile-view

Users are getting an error while opening a SharePoint Survey hosted on a SharePoint online in an Apple iPad.

> Error: Error while opening a survey hosted on a SharePoint Online in
>   Apple device.

In my site features, I have activated "`Mobile Browser View`" and still, users are getting the above error.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Do you face this issue with only survey list or the whole site?! Do you have any type of customization ?

Comment: The users are having access to Survey. Didnt test it on site,

Comment: Add a screenshot for the current survey view on your IPad? to can specify the issue faster.

Comment: Added the screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your scenario on my side and found out the following:

- This issue is not related to IPad or other mobile devices it's related to the survey list itself.
- The default survey views `(Overview, All Response, Graphic Summary)` didn't  **enabled for Mobile access** by default.
- There is no OOTB option to edit the current default views.
- There is no OOTB option to create a new view like other lists.
- If you tried to edit the view by any means you will not find the Mobile section to enable Mobile access as shown below

[image]

---

**So to overcome this issue, you should create a new view with Mobile Access Enabled.**

But as I above mentioned, There is no OOTB option to create a new view, so try to apply the below workaround

- Open Survey list setting, the URL should look like

  `http://SiteURL/_layouts/15/survedit.aspx?List=%7BB6ECB328%2D7975%2D4749%2D9E90%2DFD8634CD7A10%7D`
- Replace `survedit.aspx` with `ViewNew.aspx` , the new view page should be opened.
- Type your view name, and at Mobile section. make sure that you have the below options.

  - Enable this view for mobile access (Applies to public views only)
  - Make this view the default view for mobile access (Applies to public views only) 
    [image]
- Browse your survey that should be now browsed on Mobile.